# How to customize the onmouseover of HtmlCommandButton in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, overriding, custom-component, onmouseover, right-click

I'm new to jsf.

I would like to extend HtmlCommandButton in order to override the default behaviour of onmouseover event.

Event: OnMouseOver
Requirement: "right click" kind of functionality is expected with customized menu depending on user's role.

Would like to have expert opinions on how to proceed with this requirement.

Thanks in advance,
Arun

Answer (score 1):

As you're already using JSF 2.0, I think it's much easier to create a [composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) instead of a custom component. You then need only *one* XHTML file instead of a whole component class and/or a renderer class along with some XML config file (changes).

The composite component implementation may then look like:

```
<cc:implementation>
    <h:commandButton onmouseover="yourRightClickFunction()" ... />
</cc:implementation>
```

Then you can just use `<my:commandButton>` instead of `<h:commandButton>`.